# Prefill form not hosted in Cloud Pages

Tags: marketing-cloud

Im looking to prefill forms with marketing cloud data from the user, but when the form is not hosted in Cloudpages?
Is there a way to include a script to do this on an externally hosted page?

Thanks

Comment: Was my answer useful? If so - can you please mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a combination of [JSON Code Resource](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_create_a_code_resource.htm&type=5) in Cloud Pages and Java Script.

1. Email link will contain (preferably a hashed) unique identifier as a URL parameter
2. Landing page will contain a form and JavaScript populating it on load
3. JavaScript will forward the uid from URL to the URL of the JSON Code Resource
4. JSON Code Resource will use the passed UID to look up values needed to populate the form, in one or more Data Extensions. Here you should use [RequestParameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm) to fetch the uid and [LookupRows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm) to get the data from Data Extensions.
5. JavaScript will receive the JSON object, parse it, and populate the form fields using data received in JSON
6. Voila